# Converting a String with plain text to byte array in hex style?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, hex, implicit-conversion

i can find a lot of answer about how to convert a string in hex format to a hex byte array but I would like to know how I can convert a string with text to a byte array.

To give you an idea, here's the code for converting text into a byte array using hex format:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath);
byte[] fileInBytes;
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    List<byte> bytesList = new List<byte>();
    while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
    {
        bytesList.Add(byte.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(br.ReadBytes(2)), 
            NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    }
    fileInBytes = bytesList.ToArray();
}
return fileInBytes;
```

How can I achieve this using a String?

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromString(String str)
{
    //What now?
}
```

Basically if I enter a string that has 16 characters, I would like to return a byte array of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the number of bytes you would get back, but see below.

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromString(String str)
{
   return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)
}
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, this isn't what I need.
If I enter 16 characters, i get 16 bytes back but I want 8 bytes to be returned. So each 2 characters should form 1 byte.

Comment: Thats not possible i think .. every character is stored differently  .. you'd need at least 1 byte per character.

Comment: ASCII happens to be the smallest you can get (1 byte per character) .. for Unicode you actually can have up to 4 bytes per character i think.

Comment: It should be possible... the example function I gave you reads text from a file and does exactly that.

Comment: It seems I am mistaking, I'll change the question

Comment: Remember the ascii table ... every character is represented by 1 byte .. try counting the characters in the file yourself or make your own file with known values and count.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understand what you meam your code should look like:

public byte[] getBytesFromString2(string str)

{

```
        IList<byte> retValue = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Length == 16)
        {
            MemoryStream s_stream;

            using (s_stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)))
            {
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(s_stream))
                {
                    retValue = new List<byte>();

                    while (s_stream.Position < s_stream.Length)
                    {
                        retValue.Add(byte.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(br.ReadBytes(2)),
                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return retValue.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, maybe it will come in handy for someone who needs it. I commented on the accepted answer that I was reading the example description I was using wrong. But thanks anyway!